# pip update error after install after upgrading pip i cannot use it every time i use pip is shows same error and sudo cannot be used either to install

Tags: python, pip

today I install a module with pip for python
in the terminal it says warning new version of pip is available u can install it by using
`pip --upgrade`
And it successfully installed but
after that
whenever I try to install any module it says `pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was  included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

and i searched here and there and people say that use `sudo python -m pip --uninstall pip && sudo apt python -install pip --reinstall`

where it says the same thing but this time its

```
'sudo' : The term 'sudo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
```

included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: `sudo` is a unix command, but it sounds like you're on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to add Python and PIP to your path ([Instructions](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows)).

Also as John Gordon pointed out, sudo is a Unix/Linux command and you appear to be using Windows.

Comment: They were able to run `pip --upgrade` initially, so it's odd that pip would have disappeared from the PATH.

Answer (score -2):

Python-sudo is a Modular to execute any subprocess commands as another user.

We can install it by using pip install sudo

We know that sudo is a Linux command but we can use it in python.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).